# PHP Printing - How do I print directly from PHP on local server printer?

Tags: php, laravel, printing

I would like to print documents to my POS printer from my local server automatically.

I have tried Mike's method https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php but to no avail, this is my code.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\FilePrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\Printer;
use Mike42\Escpos\PrintConnectors\WindowsPrintConnector;
use Mike42\Escpos\CapabilityProfile;

class PrintReceipt extends Controller
{
   public function TestPrint(){
       $profile = CapabilityProfile::load("simple");
       $connector = new WindowsPrintConnector("LPT1");
       $printer = new Printer($connector, $profile);

       $printer -> text("Hello World!\n");

       $printer -> cut();

       $printer -> close();

   }
```

but I get this error:
***file_put_contents(LPT1): failed to open stream: No such file or directory***
The printer is connected and shared to the LPT1 port. Any ideeas on how to fix my code, or another way of aproaching this? I think normal printing should work as well, it does not matter if the method is for POS or not.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you do `echo "Hello World" > LPT1` on command-line? For a troubleshooting reason

Comment: You wrote LTP1 in your comment where it should be LPT1, assuming this typo was isolated to your question here?

Comment: @Eddy well, not really it tells me the file cannot find the file. What should I do?

Comment: @RoAchterberg edited the post, my bad.

Comment: _The printer is connected and shared to the LPT1 port_. How have you determined this?

Comment: @RoAchterberg i went into devices and printers and changed the port to LPT1 for my particular device

Comment: Check this example: [https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/master/example/interface/windows-lpt.php](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/master/example/interface/windows-lpt.php)

Comment: @Eddy that is basically my code, but I rewrote it again and get the same file not found error.

Comment: @CristianCutitei maybe because you can't can't connect to LPT1 port. If you got an error while `echo "Hello World" > LPT1` it seems like that.

Comment: @Eddy well i can change the port, any sugestion?

Comment: Is your LPT1 port physical or virtual? Meaning, is this an actual parallel connection or is it USB or even Ethernet? This may matter depending on the driver used.

Comment: @RoAchterberg its a usb connection

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: yes,  i followed your tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source is commented and tells you the following.

From https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/master/example/interface/windows-usb.php:

```
/**
 * Install the printer using USB printing support, and the "Generic / Text Only" driver,
 * then share it (you can use a firewall so that it can only be seen locally).
 *
 * Use a WindowsPrintConnector with the share name to print.
 *
 * Troubleshooting: Fire up a command prompt, and ensure that (if your printer is shared as
 * "Receipt Printer), the following commands work:
 *
 *  echo "Hello World" > testfile
 *  copy testfile "\\%COMPUTERNAME%\Receipt Printer"
 *  del testfile
 */
```

And from https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php/blob/development/src/Mike42/Escpos/PrintConnectors/WindowsPrintConnector.php:

```
/**
 * Connector for sending print jobs to
 * - local ports on windows (COM1, LPT1, etc)
 * - shared (SMB) printers from any platform (smb://server/foo)
 * For USB printers or other ports, the trick is to share the printer with a
 * generic text driver, then connect to the shared printer locally.
 */
```

See these articles on how to share a printer:

- https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/share-files-and-printers-in-windows-7-with-homegroup/
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/share-your-network-printer-c9a152b5-59f3-b6f3-c99f-f39e5bf664c3